# Как вывести маркер на катомних постах у WP?

Tags: wordpress

Подскажите пожалуйста, как вывести даные маркеры?

Расписывать не нужно, скажите название хука.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

я думаю вы ищете это

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'add_user_menu_bubble' );
```

[Ссылка на документацию](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/admin_menu/)